# Is there a way to upload youtube videos with a form?

Tags: php, youtube, backend

Im developing a web page with a blog style, right now I'm creating the forms to upload posts.
There's a post, in which I have to show some youtube (and also vimeo) videos.
Is there a way to upload the video just by putting the url o the key?

```
    <div class="videowrapper">
        <iframe id="player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

I would bring all url's or keys and display all videos.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: by upload you mean allowing a usert to submit a video on your page which then sends it to youtube and returns back the embedded object?

Comment: the youtube embded links have the src written like `https://www.youtube.com/embed/E7kn5bANOTA` you could use the last bit as the "key" and store that

Comment: I'm the administrator, and I need to upload a new blog post in which I want to include a youtube video, and I want to do it with a Form, so I can include a Title for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put in the form an input type of text that wants a url. After that you can get the embed url from youtube and then from then on, get the value from the database and output the url in the html. That way it would be like uploaded the url of youtube, then playing it on the site.

**Hope i help** :)

Comment: You mean by using the Insert option that every youtube video has?

Comment: Say you have a form with fields TITLE, URL, Put in title the title you want and in url the embed link of youtube then submit it. Now when retrieving data, just echo the title and put the URL an your iframe vid player and echo the link in the database as a source :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I need.

Comment: No problem, glad i could be of help :)